# Edit help text to match duplicate description, or the other way around

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, help-center

A question marked duplicate will have the following text show up in the duplicate notice on the question itself:

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question.

This seems to be inconsistent with [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions):

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please **edit this question to explain how it is different or** ask a new question.

(emphasis added)

I would suggest that these be made consistent; the wording of one should be edited to match the other.

Aside:

My personal preference is that the text that does not suggest editing remain, but I imagine this is not the consensus at least as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).  My request is simply for consistency.